# Magmi Attribute Set Importer dont set product attribute

Tags: magmi

When importing with Magmi and set Attribute Set Importer on, it does not to set the corresponding product attribute on the product itself.

I've read many posts, but no one seems to have this problem. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

- Magento: 1.9.2.4
- Magmi: 0.7.22
- Attribute Set Importer: 0.0.2

Content of the import files:

- Products file:
  sku,attribute_set,name,type,configurable_attributes,mycolor,status,weight,price,simples_skus,super_attribute_pricing
  01111,"testset","product1b","simple","mycolor","red",1,0,11,,
  01211,"testset","product2b","simple","mycolor","blue",1,0,22,,
  01422,"testset","product3b","simple","mycolor","orange",1,0,33,,
  01311,"testset","productconfigurable","configurable","mycolor",,1,0,1,"01111,01211,01422","mycolor::red:11;blue:22;orange:33"
- Attributes file:
  "attribute_code","frontend_label","frontend_input","backend_type","is_user_defined","is_required"
      "mycolor","mycolor","select","text",1,1
- Attributes Set file:
  attribute_set_name,sort_order,magmi:groups
  "testset","0","General:0,Prices:1,Meta Information:3,Images:4,Recurring Profile:4,Design:5,Gift Options:5,mycolor:6"
- Attributes Associations file:
  attribute_set_name,atttribute_code,attribute_group_name
  "testset","mycolor","General"

[Attribute not mapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcBGb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set

- backend_type

in attributes file to

- int

Event varchar didnt work.

There was no info about this, so maybe this answer is saving someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

If only I found your answer sooner, it would have saved me a few hours.

Indeed, there was no information on this subject anywhere.

If, when creating a feature via MAGMI (Attribute Set Importer / Attributes), we do not assign an appropriate backend_type parameter to it, then Magmi will set it to 'static' and then the value of such feature cannot be imported.

The feature value import worked correctly when the features had the following backend_type parameter values:

- select [dropdown]: 'int'
- multiselect: 'varchar'

---

| frontend_label | attribute_code | frontend_input | is_visible | is_searchable | is_filterable | is_visible_on_front | is_used_for_price_rules | is_user_defined | backend_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| attr1 | attr1_code | multiselect | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | varchar |
| attr2 | attr2_code | select | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | int |

Checked on Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1